# Complete active status in tmux

Tags: shell, tmux

I've been working on reimplementing powerline for tmux using just my tmux.conf instead of python.
I have almost all of what I used and needed rebuild except for handling activity statuses.

A window in my tmux sessions gets styled like this:

```
set-window-option -g window-status-format "#[fg=black, bg=black]⮀#[fg=white, bg=black] #I ⮁ #[fg=blue, bg=black] #W #[fg=black, bg=black]⮀"
```

Essentially recreating this.
[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/erikw/tmux-powerline/master/img/left-status.png]

But this is what appears to be the only option for activity status.

```
set-option -gw window-status-activity-attr bold
set-option -gw window-status-activity-bg black
set-option -gw window-status-activity-fg red
```

Or more along the lines of something like this.

```
set-option -gw window-status-activity-style fg=red,bg=black,bold
```

But when I try to incorporate the default formate for my tmux window's, I get this error

```
~/.tmux.conf:107: bad style
```

Any ideas?

Edit:

Here's what I'm trying to set for the activity style

```
set-option -gw window-status-activity-style "#[fg=black, bg=black]⮀#[fg=white, bg=black] #I ⮁ #[fg=blue, bg=black] #W #[fg=black, bg=black]⮀"
```

Comment: what is in line 107?

Comment: The status line for my tmux activity style. I've added it to the post

Comment: you can only set style with comma separated values like `"fg=xxx,bg=xxx,bold"` what you were trying to do is `FORMATS` value.

Comment: So `window-status-activity-format` would work for this?

Comment: I don't see the option in man page...

Comment: Ahh I was looking at an old mailing list. Doesn't seem to be possible. Want to post your `styles` comment and I'll mark that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that there there is a flag for this.
With complex status bars, you can't simply use `window-status-active`, but the flag `#{?window_activity_flag`

[See my tmux config](https://github.com/mhartington/dotfiles/blob/master/config/tmux-status.conf#L26)

Answer (score 0):

you can only set style with comma separated values like `"fg=xxx,bg=xxx,bold"` what you were trying to do is `FORMATS` value. –  Kent